# Failed to include file in php

Tags: php

```
->MainFolder
    ->folderA
        ->functionA.php

    ->folderB
        ->folderB2
            ->functionB.php
```

I trying to include "functionA.php"  in my "functionB.php"

> When i write 
>   "include('../../folderA/functionA.php')", the function inside "functionA.php" doesn't work in "functionB.php".

But the function works

> when i write in "include('../folderA/functionA.php')"

I wonder why only up one level folder can run the function inside "functionA.php"

Comment: Are you calling `functionB.php` directly, or does it itself get included from a different location …?

Comment: @misorude functionB.php was included by another file

Comment: The path of the “main” script is the one that is used to complete relative paths. You can use the `__DIR__` constant in functionB.php to get the full path to that file, and navigate your way to A from there. http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: @misorude thx for the info. btw , is it a bad idea if i just let it be "include('../folderA/functionA.php')" in my functionB.php?

Comment: That would fail if you included B in a different script that is in a different location than the one that is currently including it.

Comment: @misorude i see, thx